# Adding to Eclipse's console view pop-up menu

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse plugin development, I have been able to add an item to the right-click context menu on the project explorer by doing this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
        <command ... >
            ...
        </command>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

But when I try to add to the pop-up menu for the ConsoleView, I'm not getting results.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView">
        <command ... >
            ...
        </command>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

I've been looking at the output from alt-shift-F1 and alt-shift-F2 (Plug-in Spy), which is where I got `org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView`.  But I can't seem to get to the pop-up menu itself.  I can get information about the individual pop-up menu items (Select All, Clear, etc), but I guess I just don't quite know how to "dig" with Plug-in Spy to get the right information.

**EDIT: Showing the results of my work using the answer from below**

Plug-in Selection Spy had the following:

```
Active Part (Console)
    The active view identifier:
        org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView
Active Selection
    The selection class:
        TextSelection
Active Help
    The active help context identifiers:
        org.eclipse.debug.ui.process_console_context
```

It was that last entry which pointed me toward the **process console** as opposed to the message console.  The link in the answer had `IDebugUIConstants.ID_PROCESS_CONSOLE_TYPE` defined as `org.eclipse.debug.ui.ProcessConsoleType`.  So I ended up with this, and it worked:

```
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.debug.ui.ProcessConsoleType.#ContextMenu">
     <command
           commandId="com.grch.cmgtsdk.merge"
           label="Yowza!"
           style="push">
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Console view itself is just a container for different kinds of consoles and it doesn't have a context menu. You need to figure out the menu ID of the specific console that you want to add your contribution to.

For text consoles the menu ID looks something like `<console type>.#ContextMenu`. This is not really documented and finding out the *console type* is not straightforward (you should look into the code). For example, console type of process console is defined in [`IDebugUIConstants.ID_PROCESS_CONSOLE_TYPE`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/ui/IDebugUIConstants.html) whereas for message console it's [`IConsoleConstants.MESSAGE_CONSOLE_TYPE`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/console/IConsoleConstants.html).

Answer (score 1):

Above answer helped me in creating the popup. Below is the example code:-

```
<menuContribution
           locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.MessageConsole.#ContextMenu">
           <menu
                 label="My Popup" id="com.abhi.test.popup.menu2">

           <command
                 commandId="com.abhi.test.command1"
                 id="com.abhi.test.popup.command3"
                 style="push">
           </command>
           </menu>
     </menuContribution>
```